# Scraping image dataset from the web using python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, computer-vision, python-imaging-library, google-image-search

I want to get a huge dataset of images to use for computer vision.

So I need to download from the internet images given a query (in the example "faces").

I have been trying to use google images api but got around 60 images and no more.
With this trick I can get up to 100...

```
import re
import subprocess
import urllib2

#Parameters
query = "face"
AGENT_ID   = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1"
GOOGLE_URL = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+ query +\
"&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=T2KSUtD4Hsim4gSwmYGIBw&sqi=2&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1104&bih=591"

#The main line
html_page = subprocess.check_output(["curl", "-L", "-A", AGENT_ID, GOOGLE_URL], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

# Parsing out the images urls
results = []
for division in re.findall(r'<div.*?</div>(?ims)', html_page):
    try:
        results.append(re.findall(r'imgurl=&amp|imgurl=(.*?\.(?:jpg|gif|png|jpeg|bmp))(?ims)', division)[0])
    except IndexError:
        pass
results = [i for i in  results if i != ""]
```

Any idea how to get around 500 images or more?

Comment: Sidenote: you should consider using Scrapy to do this (http://scrapy.org/) It would be a much more robust solution.

Comment: Check out [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and perhaps you'll reach the end of the google image search's infinite scroll :P

Comment: also check [beautifulsoup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4)

Comment: @kroolik Thanks a lot!!! I do:
`driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")`
At this point how do I get the images urls?

Comment: May not fit your task but there are all sorts of datasets such as http://groups.csail.mit.edu/vision/SUN/ and http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/lfw/ available

Comment: I agree with @MaciejGol. If you want extract everything from Google Images, Selenium seems the way to go.